# WinRT/Phone 8.1 - Listening To Manipulations Inside ScrollViewer

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone

I simply cannot find a way to get a ScrollViewer to share manipulation events. As soon as I put something inside a ScrollViewer and then set that items ManipulationMode, the ScrollViewer stops working

I have read that the ScrollViewer handles all of these events and stops them bubbling up, but there MUST be a way to get around this without disabling the ScrollViewer's scrolling behaviour.

I am very simply trying to implement a horizontal swipe feature on items in an ItemsControl, which is inside a ScrollViewer. (I have disabled the ScrollViewer's Horizontal scrolling mechanisms to no avail)

Without the ScrollViewer wrapped around it, everything works fine.

Any ideas anyone ? I cannot believe that this simple UI gesture cannot be implemented.

Many thanks

Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ListView` to get the built-in cross-slide/swipe behavior if that's what you need. Otherwise - the [last time](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/d82d366f-71c9-4e63-9a2f-e400f97950df) I had to implement dragging out of a list - I put a rectangle in front of the `ScrollViewer` and captured all input events and then manually handled `ScrollViewer` scrolling. It's a bad idea, but there is no better choice yet.

Comment: I tried manually handling ScrollViewer scrolling but you dont get any intertia animations if you just scroll to an offset. I'll give ListView another go - thanks

Comment: You can get inertia if you use `ManipulationModes.TranslateInertia`.

Comment: There doesnt seem to be any way of tapping into the ListView manipulations either. The manipulation events on a ListView dont seem to fire.Im just going round and round on this one, and there seems to be no example code for anything like this

Comment: `ListView` really has a `ScrollViewer` inside of it, so the best customizations there are either to put a manipulations capture element in front of it and control the `ScrollViewer` manually or in some cases it might be enough to put a `ScrollViewer` inside of the `ScrollViewer`. Think about putting a horizontally scrollable `ScrollViewer` inside of each item of the vertically scrollable `ListView`. It's a horrible hack, but it might work for your case until anything better is exposed by the platform.

Comment: I finally got it to work by having an ItemsControl inside a ScrollViewer, and a transparent Grid covering everything. The Grid handled the manipulations and passed scrolling info to the ScrollViewer and swipe info to the individual items in the ItemsControl. The only thing Im missing is the rebouce (ScrollViewer compression) which I cant seem to invoke - but I'm not too bothered about that small detail. Thanks for all the advice